# How to switch the linked Github repository from one local reposity to another

Tags: github

I am working on a version of the same application, and the main remote repository on GitHub only link to one of the local repository.

Now I want to switch the linking from one local project folder to another, which makes a new commit to the remote repository, which the new folder code will replace all the original code on it. How can I do that?